# Running an application before system start-up

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

From my understanding, it is possible to have programs run before system start-up (e.g. Login screen) with a Windows Service.  I'm using VS2010 and VB.net.  I need to be able to start a server with my program that can be managed from the login screen.  Is this possible?  If so, how would I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "managed from login screen"?  You won't be able to add any type of interface to the login screen without some major work (you'll have to write your own login manager for windows).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is possible.  You'll need to write a `Windows Service` application.  Once you've written this, you then install it on the server.  Configure the service so that it starts when the server starts and you are away.

[Creating a Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx)

[Add Installers to your Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddhy0byf.aspx)

[Install and Uninstall Windows Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd8zc8ha.aspx)